# How to solve this improper integral $\int_{2}^{\infty}\frac{x}{x^3-2\sin x}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

How should I solve this improper integral ?
$$\int_{2}^{\infty}\frac{x}{x^3-2\sin x}dx$$
I tried symbolab integral calculator but it was unable to solve. Any suggestions would be appreciated! Thank you

Comment: Do you want an exact form or just want to prove the convergence?

Comment: @ArchisWelankar I want to check if this will converge or diverge

Answer (score 1):

We know that $-1\leq \sin(x)\leq 1$ thus $\int_2^{\infty} \frac{xdx}{x^3-2\sin(x)} < \int_2^{\infty} \frac{xdx}{x^3-2}$ the latter integral is comparable $\frac{1}{x^2}$ when $x$ becomes very large. You can find the integrand of $\int \frac{xdx}{x^3-2}$ manually thus the original integral converges.